# Sails js custom/calculated attributes is not working, using code from sails docs

Tags: sails.js, waterline, calculated-columns, calculated-field, custom-attribute

I have this model that is taken from this [sails documentation page](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models#?attribute-methods-(ie-record%2Finstance-methods))

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
    // Primitive attributes
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },

    // Attribute methods
    getFullName: function (){
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
};
```

What I expect when I call my auto generated restful api (using blueprint)

> localhost:port/resourceName

is

> {"firstName":"john", "lastName":"Doe", "getFullName": "john Doe"}

instead what I am getting is this

> {"firstName":"john", "lastName":"Doe"}

any ideas?

I already checked other posts such as this one [github](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/626).

sails version: 0.11.4

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the custom attribute to be serialised you can override the default [toJSON](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) instance method:

```
toJSON: function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  obj.fullName = this.getFullName();
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Using question code and answer code produces "TypeError: obj.getFullName is not a function" but works with primitive types. @scroggins

Comment: Sorry, have updated. Needed to use 'this.getFullName()'